# What causes the 'A member defining the identity of the object cannot be changed` error on a SQL update?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, visual-studio-2010, sql-update

What is causing this error message when I try to update a record returned from a LINQ query:

> Value of member 'statusId' of an object of type 'Employee' changed.A
> member defining the identity of the object cannot be changed. Consider
> adding a new object with new identity and deleting the existing one
> instead.

I want to query for `statusId` from my `EmployeeDetails` table and change it to '0' from '1'. How do I fix this?

## Query and modify statement

```
//disable invalid accounts
    private static bool DisableADUser(string samAccountName)
    {
        bool result = false;
        try
        {
            string name = samAccountName;
            //Attach the log to show generated SQL.
            db.Log = Console.Out;

            //Query for account status
            var disable = from emp in db.EmployeeDetails
                          where emp.employeeName == name
                          select emp;
            foreach (var q in disable)
            {
                q.statusId = "0";

                if (q.statusId == "0")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("disabled:");
                    result = true;
                }
            }
            db.SubmitChanges();
            //Query for account status
            var query = from emp in db.EmployeeDetails
                        join stat in db.Status on emp.statusId equals stat.statusId
                        join dep in db.Department on emp.departmentId equals dep.departmentId
                        where emp.employeeName == name
                        select new { emp, stat, dep };
            foreach (var q in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Dep: {0,2} \tName: {1,2} \tStatus: {2,2}",
                    q.dep.departmentName,
                    q.emp.employeeName,
                    q.stat.statusDescription);
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

This is a screenshot of the error message that I'm getting:
[image: Error:A member defining the identity of the object cannot be changed]

EDIT:

Here is the sql create table script.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeDetails](
[employeeId] [int] NOT NULL,
[employeeName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[employeeAge] [int] NULL,
[userId] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[password] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[departmentId] [int] NULL,
[zoneId] [int] NULL,
[statusId] [int] NULL,
[startDate] [date] NULL,
[expiryDate] [date] NULL,
[typeId] [int] NOT NULL,
[hashPassword] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
```

And this is my employee definition:

```
 [Database]
public class FireEvacuation : DataContext
{
    public Table<Employee> EmployeeDetails;
    public Table<EmpDepartment> Department;
    public Table<EmpStatus> Status;

    public FireEvacuation(string connection) : base(connection) { }
}
```

SOLVED:
The problem was with Employee status Id being incorrectly set as a primary key. Turns out my code was fine.

Comment: "A member defining the identity of an object cannot be changed" is a pretty good clue.  can you post your SQL table script?  Also give this a read http://www.singingeels.com/Blogs/Nullable/2009/01/09/How_to_Make_LINQ_to_SQL_Check_for_Changes_After_Attach_or_AttachAll.aspx

Comment: Also post the Employee class definition.

Comment: The error message is pretty self explanatory. Looks like your `Employee` entity uses `statusId` as identity property. And you cannot change identity for existing instance just like that.

Comment: In that case, how am I able to modify the status Id of the employees?

Comment: Check your `Employee` class and corresponding table. Or provide their definitions here.

Comment: You probably have wrong relations design. And `statusId` appeared to be primary key for `Employee` instead of foreign key to `EmpStatus`.

Comment: Yup you're right. The issue was with the status Id being a primary key. Thank you!