# System.InvalidOperationException "Value of member X of an object of type Y changed" when updating an object in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, invalidoperationexception

I got a problem with this exception
'Value of member X of an object of type Y changed.
A member defining the identity of the object cannot be changed.
Consider adding a new object with new identity and deleting the existing one instead.'
[image: This is my edit method in controller]
[image: This is my model]

I try to test some different case testing identify, testing length of string,... but i can't solve this, I hope somebody can help me as soon as posible. Thanks

Comment: Welcome! Please read and apply: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/11107541). Set the right expectation for yourself that [you may need to wait patiently for an answer](/help/no-one-answers).

Comment: Please read [ask]. Do not post code as images (post as text) and try to provide all relevant parts [mre] would be great.

Comment: You are not updating "via LINQ". You are finding an object with LINQ, but that is unlikely to be related to your issue. Please consider questions and tags carefully when posting problems.

Comment: On what line is the exception occurring? Have you looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29641183/2557128)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sounds like you're trying to change the primary key of an existing record in a database table. Have you tried deleting the existing record and creating a new one as suggested by the error message? If so, what happened? Also, please take note of the previous comments on how to ask a good question.